# How to get attribute value of nested element using jackson xml?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml, jackson-modules

I appear to have run into a limitation of Jackson XML but wanted to ask the community first to see if I am missing something. Given the following xml:

```html
<Element1>
  <Element2 attribute="Some String">Some element value</Element2>
<Element1>
```

Is it possible to create a POJO to deserialize the attribute value of Element2? My current POJO looks like:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Element1")
public class Element1 implements Serializable {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String attribute;

}
```

This returns the value of the Element2 tag which in this case is "Some element value". However if I move the attribute to the Element1 tag, this same code is able to retrieve the attribute value. Is there some limitation of jackson xml to get nested attributes? I have also tried specifying the localname of the attribute but that doesnt work either. I feel I am missing something or this is a limitation of the library. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to read a nested xml tag with an [incremental reading](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml): basically you have to create an [`XMLStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) streamreader and set it manually so that points to the `Element2` nested tag. Your xmlmapper will read the nested tag using the pointing xmlstreamreader like below:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Element2 {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String attribute;
}


File xml = new File("msg.xml");
XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader sr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xml));
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
sr.nextTag(); //<--point to Element1
sr.nextTag(); //<--point to Element2
//now you can deserialize the nested xml tag
Element2 element2 = mapper.readValue(sr, Element2.class);
sr.close(); //<-- closing the stream
```

Comment: That does work so marked as accepted. But still wondering if there is a cleaner way. If the xml was large you would basically have to step through each tag manually.

Comment: @humiliatedpenguin Correct, but this is the way because jackson for xml is based on stax,with the json format things are simpler.